# Is there a scene graph concept in VTK?

Tags: python, vtk

I'm looking for a 3d visualization framework in python that implements something similar to a scene graph. Specifically, I would like to be able to define the pose (XYZRPY) of one element in the scene with respect to another element in the scene. I have been reading through the documentation for VTK, but I haven't seen any functionality like this yet. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I never used it, but I suppose [vtkViewNode](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkViewNode.html) and inherited classes (f.ex. vtkActorNode) are what you need:

> This is the superclass for all nodes within a VTK scene graph. It contains the API for a node. It supports the essential operations such as graph creation, state storage and traversal. Child classes adapt this to VTK's major rendering classes. Grandchild classes adapt those to for APIs of different rendering libraries.

These classes are not documented in the VTK User Guide, you can find them in the nightly builds doc so they are released and working (I confirm I have them in my 8.0.1 build). You should look at the SetChildren call to build your graph. Unfortunately the file readers in vtk do not load the scene hierarchy, so you'll need to build the graph explicitely or to write your own readers.